# Build System in Sublime Text to work with Grunt

Tags: html, gruntjs, sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I need to adjust to Build Systems Sublime Text3 to work with Grunt. To compile SCSS to CSS by the keyboard shortcut `ctrl + b`. I downloaded the plugin, but `ctrl + b` does not work there. Write Build himself I can not. Lack experience. Need to write to build for hot keys `ctrl + b`. I would be grateful for your help and understanding.

Comment: Have a look at the Tool menu, sometimes the build system is giving me troubles when set to “automatic.” It might work when you manually choose Grunt.

Comment: Assuming you've installed grunt, then use Tools > Build System > New Build System... to setup the command as a build option, in my case in Windows "shell_cmd": "grunt". Is that what you are asking for help with?